I tried to update Adguard running on Portainer and now it is broken. Can't access the web UI
I intended to update all my containers running in Portainer to the latest version. For that I ran the following commands in order to update the containers:
First I ran:
docker-compose pull

Then I ran:
docker compose up -d

After that, all my containers were recreated and were up and running except AdGuard (it says it was running, but I was not able to access adguard web page) In case is need it, I'm running this on a rasberry pi. The code below in the content of my docker-compose.yaml:
  adguardhome:
    image: adguard/adguardhome
    container_name: adguardhome
    ports:
      - 53:53/tcp
      - 53:53/udp
      - 784:784/udp
      - 853:853/tcp
      - 3000:3000/tcp
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    volumes:
      - ./workdir:/opt/adguardhome/work
      - ./confdir:/opt/adguardhome/conf
    restart: unless-stopped

The following are the logs I see in Portainer for the AdGuard Container:
2024/05/23 22:07:30.796268 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:08:31.995573 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:08:32.000408 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:08:32.008678 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:08:32.024386 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:08:32.024769 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:08:32.024803 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:08:32.024814 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:08:32.499008 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:08:32.499064 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:09:33.718637 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:09:33.723127 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:09:33.732938 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:09:33.746133 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:09:33.746678 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:09:33.747026 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:09:33.747131 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:09:34.211278 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:09:34.211459 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:10:35.397561 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:10:35.402189 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:10:35.409646 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:10:35.425300 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:10:35.425701 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:10:35.425797 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:10:35.425888 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:10:35.889522 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:10:35.889705 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:11:37.544844 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:11:37.549476 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:11:37.557202 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:11:37.632589 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:11:37.633124 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:11:37.633314 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:11:37.633330 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:11:38.118330 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:11:38.118398 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:12:39.353204 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:12:39.358001 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:12:39.365848 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:12:39.382490 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:12:39.382962 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:12:39.382996 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:12:39.383007 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:12:39.851063 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:12:39.851142 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:13:41.076814 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:13:41.080952 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:13:41.088302 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:13:41.102994 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:13:41.103270 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:13:41.103304 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:13:41.103315 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:13:41.574671 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:13:41.574766 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:14:42.806020 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:14:42.810292 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:14:42.817993 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:14:42.833051 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:14:42.833386 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:14:42.833421 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:14:42.833544 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:14:43.284399 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:14:43.284476 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:15:44.500500 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:15:44.504688 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:15:44.512337 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:15:44.529474 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:15:44.529981 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:15:44.530018 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:15:44.530029 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:15:44.992893 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:15:44.992942 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:16:46.201493 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:16:46.207337 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:16:46.215686 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:16:46.229736 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:16:46.230389 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:16:46.230512 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:16:46.230640 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:16:46.702967 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:16:46.703018 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:17:47.889942 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:17:47.894829 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:17:47.902297 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:17:47.918477 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:17:47.918815 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:17:47.918969 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:17:47.918985 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:17:48.379019 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:17:48.379070 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified
2024/05/23 22:18:49.576847 \[info\] AdGuard Home, version v0.107.49
2024/05/23 22:18:49.582526 \[info\] tls: using default ciphers
2024/05/23 22:18:49.590257 \[info\] safesearch default: reset 248 rules
2024/05/23 22:18:49.605458 \[info\] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2024/05/23 22:18:49.605758 \[info\] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:2
2024/05/23 22:18:49.605791 \[info\] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2024/05/23 22:18:49.605851 \[info\] web: initializing
2024/05/23 22:18:50.065273 \[error\] querylog: closing: flushing log buffer: nothing to write to a file
2024/05/23 22:18:50.065463 \[fatal\] dnsServer.Prepare: preparing internal proxy: validating private RDNS upstreams: no upstream specified


I don't know if there is something wrong with the latest version, but I managed to solve it by specifying the version in the .yaml file like this:
adguardhome:
image: adguard/adguardhome:v0.107.48
container_name: adguardhome
ports:
  - 53:53/tcp
  - 53:53/udp
  - 784:784/udp
  - 853:853/tcp
  - 3000:3000/tcp
  - 80:80/tcp
  - 443:443/tcp
volumes:
  - ./workdir:/opt/adguardhome/work
  - ./confdir:/opt/adguardhome/conf
restart: unless-stoppedv0.107.48

